# Trying to read titles from urls in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a function to call the title of a given url for google spreadsheets. Now, it seems very inconsistent as sometimes I refresh the code and it works and sometimes I get the following error for the very same url that worked previously:

TypeError: Cannot read property "title" from undefined.

I mean, all the links have titles so I am not sure what this means? sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't..

```
   function GrabTitle(URL) {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
          var doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(),true);
          var title = doc.html.head.title.getText();
      if (title == '') {
        return "unknown";
      }
        else {
          return title;  
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked that the response is being set?

Comment: how would I check that?

Comment: It could not parse the text. Though it is inconsistent as it works sometimes

Comment: Ok, I have found that the response is sometimes returning an empty string. It seems to take an average of 6 attempts to return a value and thus causing a service invoked too many times issue